# Create a New Array in Clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

When I use `[]` the expression gets compiled to `cljs.core.PersistentVector.EMPTY` which looks like all expressions of `[]` map to the same object.

I've read that I [shouldn't use `new Array()`](https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w). Is that still worth following?

Since I'm going to call `aset` on this Array, I need a new object with each call. How would I do that?

Comment: Probably with some code even if it is JS we can help you see the idiomatic way in clojurescript better

Answer (score 7):

There’s pretty neat notation in ClojureScript nowadays. You can just type `#js []` and compiler will treat it as native JS array. Works with objects too, like so: `#js {:one 1 :two 2}`. Such thing will be compiled to bare JS object.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are doing JavaScript interop you should just use persistent vectors. If you really need to make an array you can do so with `(array)`.